# Strange ALSA monitor device behaviour

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, audio-recording, alsa

Faced strange ALSA monitor device behaviour while recording sound using C++ with Qt 5.5.1 framework on Ubuntu 16.04.1 amd64. Count of bytes read from monitor device (input device which replays sound sent to ALSA output device) vastly differs from count of bytes read from microphone for same period of time. For example monitor read bytes count is 31760 bytes more than read from microphone when recording for just 5 seconds at sample rate 44100 with S16LE sample. If I actually play something - difference is even more, up to 648160 bytes.

I've written demo program, as minimalistic as it possible for this case ([source code archive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2RhVTpvm0MaemZuZ0RBZU50WHc/view?usp=sharing) - just short main.cpp and simple class). It runs three tests - one when nothing is played in speakers, second when I play a lot of short `tada.wav` sound using `aplay`, third when I play just few such sounds.

Here is output of this program:

```
===> TEST MONITOR SILENCE
Microphone audio input device: "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
Monitor audio input device: "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor"
Bytes read from microphone: 421040
Bytes read from monitor: 452800
Difference between bytes read from microphone and monitor: 31760
5.003 seconds elapsed

===> TEST MONITOR LOT OF TADA
Microphone audio input device: "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
Monitor audio input device: "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor"
Bytes read from microphone: 435840
Bytes read from monitor: 1084000
Difference between bytes read from microphone and monitor: 648160
5.002 seconds elapsed

===> TEST MONITOR FEW TADA
Microphone audio input device: "alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo"
Monitor audio input device: "alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor"
Bytes read from microphone: 435520
Bytes read from monitor: 559702
Difference between bytes read from microphone and monitor: 124182
5.001 seconds elapsed

----
Difference ratio (lot of tada / silence): 20.4081
Difference ratio (one tada / silence): 3.91001
```

As you see, difference between monitor/microphone bytes count increases ~4 times if I simple play few short sounds and even 20 (!) times when there are a lot of sounds played. It does not matter whether I run sound playing command from Qt program or manually using terminal. Tested also on Ubuntu 14.04 with Qt 5.6.1 - same thing. Tried to use PulseAudio directly with help of [enter link description here](https://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/doxygen/parec-simple_8c-example.html), executed it in one shell for 28 secs and executed 20 tada.wav in for loop in other shell - read bytes count is 1.8 more in comparison with silence.

Just for comparison, here is output of this program built in Windows 10 with Qt 5.6.1 (I've only replaced audio device names and sound play command to VLC):

```
===> TEST MONITOR SILENCE
Microphone audio input device: "Microphone (2- Realtek High Definition Audio)"
Monitor audio input device: "Stereo mixer (2- Realtek High Definition Audio)"
Bytes read from microphone: 437472
Bytes read from monitor: 437472
Difference between bytes read from microphone and monitor: 0
5.08 seconds elapsed

===> TEST MONITOR LOT OF TADA
Microphone audio input device: "Microphone (2- Realtek High Definition Audio)"
Monitor audio input device: "Stereo mixer (2- Realtek High Definition Audio)"
Bytes read from microphone: 437472
Bytes read from monitor: 437472
Difference between bytes read from microphone and monitor: 0
5.051 seconds elapsed

===> TEST MONITOR FEW TADA
Microphone audio input device: "Microphone (2- Realtek High Definition Audio)"
Monitor audio input device: "Stereo mixer (2- Realtek High Definition Audio)"
Bytes read from microphone: 437472
Bytes read from monitor: 437472
Difference between bytes read from microphone and monitor: 0
5.03 seconds elapsed

----
Difference ratio (lot of tada / silence): nan
Difference ratio (one tada / silence): nan
```

As you see here is absolutely no difference between read bytes cound, or as I see in other runs - there could be a very little difference equal to buffer size in one readyRead emit, which is caused just because of kind of race situation between microphone and stereo mixer signals.

Could anybody suggest how to solve described problem with ALSA in Qt and Ubuntu? This strange behaviour cause troubles with AEC code in my real project.

Comment: This question could be marked as duplicate cause I've reduced problem show case to simple PulseAudio C++ code, posted it in separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847039/strange-pulseaudio-monitor-device-behaviour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange PulseAudio monitor device behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847039/strange-pulseaudio-monitor-device-behaviour)